# How to pre-populate date field in .NET Core Razor pages?

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor

I'm trying to pre-populate a date form field with today's date on a scaffolded Razor Pages form. I've tried setting class variables in the OnGet function, and I've also tried setting the value (below) or even the placeholder. No luck.

.Net Core 3.0 C# web application Razor pages (not MVC).

Both of the following date pickers show the correct date in the value when I view the page source, but when the pages loads all I get is mm/dd/yyyy in the picker. I want it to show that date to the user on page load.

```
<input asp-for="VideoAccess.AccessStartDate" value="@DateTime.Now" class="form-control" />
<input type="datetime-local" value="@DateTime.Now.ToString()" class="form-control" />
```

All wrapped in the Visual Studio generated code scaffold. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You just assign today's date to the datetime property of your page model **before** you return the page in *OnGet()* method, and then return the page.

Let's demonstrate this by using Microsoft's [Razor Pages with Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET Core Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#the-student-entity) Instructor Entity

For example, lets look at the relevant parts from Create [Page](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/data/ef-rp/intro/samples/cu30/Pages/Instructors/Create.cshtml) and [PageModel](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/data/ef-rp/intro/samples/cu30/Pages/Instructors/Create.cshtml.cs)

Pages/Instructors/Create.cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Instructor.HireDate" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Instructor.HireDate" class="form-control"/>
    <span asp-validation-for="Instructor.HireDate" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Pages/Instructors/Create.cshtml.cs: (Removed irrelevant parts)

```cs
    [BindProperty]
    public Instructor Instructor { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        Instructor ??= new Instructor{ HireDate = DateTime.Now };
        return Page();
    }
```

This line `Instructor ??= new Instructor{ HireDate = DateTime.Now };` assigns current datetime value to the model-bound property **Instructor**. The page handles the rest.